# Why Prometheus pod pending after setup it by helm in Kubernetes cluster on Rancher server?

Tags: vagrant, kubernetes, prometheus, rancher, kubernetes-helm

Installed Rancher server and 2 Rancher agents in Vagrant. Then switch to K8S environment from Rancher server.

On Rancher server host, installed `kubectl` and `helm`. Then installed `Prometheus` by `Helm`:

```
helm install stable/prometheus
```

Now check the status from Kubernetes dashboard, there are 2 pods pending:
[image]

It noticed `PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound`, so aren't the K8S components been installed default with Rancher server?

(another name, same issue)
[image]

## Edit

```
> kubectl get pvc
NAME                                   STATUS    VOLUME    CAPACITY   
ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
voting-prawn-prometheus-alertmanager   Pending                                                     6h
voting-prawn-prometheus-server         Pending                                                     6h
> kubectl get pv
No resources found.
```

## Edit 2

```
$ kubectl describe pvc voting-prawn-prometheus-alertmanager
Name:          voting-prawn-prometheus-alertmanager
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        app=prometheus
               chart=prometheus-4.6.9
               component=alertmanager
               heritage=Tiller
               release=voting-prawn
Annotations:   <none>
Capacity:
Access Modes:
Events:
  Type    Reason         Age                From                         Message
  ----    ------         ----               ----                         -------
  Normal  FailedBinding  12s (x10 over 2m)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set

$ kubectl describe pvc voting-prawn-prometheus-server
Name:          voting-prawn-prometheus-server
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        app=prometheus
               chart=prometheus-4.6.9
               component=server
               heritage=Tiller
               release=voting-prawn
Annotations:   <none>
Capacity:
Access Modes:
Events:
  Type    Reason         Age                From                         Message
  ----    ------         ----               ----                         -------
  Normal  FailedBinding  12s (x14 over 3m)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl get pvc,pv`?

Comment: @Nickolay I added results of your command.

Comment: And please add output of `kubectl describe pvc <pvc_name>` as well

Comment: @Nickolay Added. `Edit 2`

Comment: @online: have you found a solution yet? Am facing the same issue :(

Answer (score 6):

I had same issues as you.  I found two ways to solve this:

- edit `values.yaml` under `persistentVolumes.enabled=false` this will allow you to use `emptyDir` "this applies to Prometheus-Server and AlertManager"
- If you can't change `values.yaml` you will have to create the PV before deploying the chart so that the pod can bind to the volume otherwise it will stay in the pending state forever

Comment: This helped me even on a bare-metal cluster without Rancher.

Comment: `emptyDir` is ephemeral, meaning that when the associated Pod is deleted, it will be gone forever.

Comment: Therefore, this is not a solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75392879/issues-setting-up-prometheus-on-eks-pods-in-pending-state-seems-to-be-depende 

for detailed process to use PVC not `emptyDir`

Answer (score 1):

PV are cluster scoped and PVC are namespaced scope.
If your application running in a different namespace and PVC in a different namespace, it can be issue.
If yes, use RBAC to give proper permissions, or put app and PVC in same namespace.

Can you make sure PV which is getting created from Storage class is the default SC of the cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that i was missing storage class and storage volumes. fixed similar problems on my cluster by first creating a storage class.

```
kubectl apply -f storageclass.ymal 

storageclass.ymal:
    {
      "kind": "StorageClass",
      "apiVersion": "storage.k8s.io/v1",
      "metadata": {
        "name": "local-storage",
        "annotations": {
          "storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class": "true"
        }
      },
      "provisioner": "kubernetes.io/no-provisioner",
      "reclaimPolicy": "Delete"
```

and the using the storage class when install Prometheus with helm

```
helm install stable/prometheus --set server.storageClass=local-storage
```

and i was also forced to create a volume for Prometheus to bind to

```
kubectl apply -f prometheusVolume.yaml

prometheusVolume.yaml:    
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolume
    metadata:
      name: prometheus-volume
    spec:
      storageClassName: local-storage
      capacity:
        storage: 2Gi #Size of the volume
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce #type of access
      hostPath:
        path: "/mnt/data" #host location
```

You could use other storage classes, found that there as a lot to chose between but then there might be other steps involved to get it working.