# Issues setting up Prometheus on EKS - Pods in Pending State (Seems to be dependent on PVCs waiting on Volume being created)

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster for my university project and I want to setup Prometheus on the cluster. To do this I am using helm with the following commands (see this tutorial https://archive.eksworkshop.com/intermediate/240_monitoring/deploy-prometheus/):

```
kubectl create namespace prometheus

helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts

helm install prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus \
    --namespace prometheus \
    --set alertmanager.persistentVolume.storageClass="gp2" \
    --set server.persistentVolume.storageClass="gp2"
```

When I check the status of the prometheus pods, the alert-manager and server seem to be in an infinite Pending state:
[image]

When I describe the prometheus-alertmanager-0 pod I see the following VolumeBinding error:
[image]

When I describe the prometheus-server-5d858bd4bd-6xmws pod I see the following VolumeBinding error:
[image]

I can also see there are 2 pvcs in Pending state:
[image]

When I describe the prometheus-server pvc, I can see its waiting for a volume to be created:
[image]

Im familiar with Kubernetes basics but pvcs is not something that I have used before. Is the solution here to create a "volume" and if so how do I do that?, would that solve the issue?, or am I way off the mark?

Should I try to install Prometheus in a different way?

Any help on this greatly appreciated

Note: Although similar this is not a duplicate of [Prometheus server in pending state after installation using Helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57523549/prometheus-server-in-pending-state-after-installation-using-helm). For one the errors highlighted there are different errors, also other manual steps such as creating volumes were also performed (which I have not done), Finally,  I am following the specific tutorial referenced and also I am asking if I should try to setup Prometheus a different way if there is a simpler way

Comment: Yes, it seems that you are missing a persistent volume which is expected by the PVC and further by the pod . For the dynamic provisioning of PVs in your cluster you need either an `EFS-CSI` or `EBS-CSI` controller.
Please follow this article for step by step guide [eks-persistent-storage](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-persistent-storage/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS) Container Storage Interface (CSI) driver onto your Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS) cluster. This will enable the creation of Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) volumes from within the EKS environment through the utilization of the `ebs-csi-driver-controller` when Persistent Volume Claims (PVCs) are initiated.
2. Ensure that the `ebs-csi-driver-controller` possesses the appropriate AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) permissions necessary for generating EC2 volumes using an IAM role. To accomplish this, create an IAM role designated as `ebs-csi-driver-controller-role`. Attach the policy with the ARN `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy` to this role.
3. Subsequently, associate the `ebs-csi-driver-controller-role` IAM role with the controller. This can be achieved by employing an annotation on the `serviceAccount` element within the deployment configuration, as demonstrated below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: <service-account-name>
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/ebs-csi-driver-controller-role
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have CSI driver already installed while running the EKS cluster.

Step1:- Check the logs of pod ebs-csi-controller-pod
If it says like

> could not create volume in EC2: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation

Then Perform below steps to get the prometheus pods running.

Step2:- Create an IAM role name as <AmazonEKS_EBS_CSI_DriverRole> with AWS Policy AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy and attach the OIDC details of respective cluster in Trust Relationship section as below.

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "<oidc_arn_of_cluster>"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "oidc.eks.<region>.amazonaws.com/id/<enterclusterid>:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note:- In case you have sys at the end of above oidc code, change that to aud as mentioned above.

Step3:- Now go to Cluster and edit the ebs-csi-controller-sa

```
kubectl edit sa ebs-csi-controller-sa -n kube-system
```

And put under metadata like below, pls correct the indetation

```
metadata:
 annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: 
         arn:aws:iam::<awsaccountid>:role/<AmazonEKS_EBS_CSI_DriverRole>
```

Step4:- Then restart the deployment

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment ebs-csi-controller -n kube-system
```

Thats it, you should be having PV bounded and running pod of prometheus server pods.